# Google search Java API

Tags: java, google-search-api

How do we get more Google search results in Java against the query by using Google API which returns JSON?  I have used the API but it only returns top 4 results.  What I want is to get more results i.e. the top 100 results.

Comment: Hi, Did you got any way to get more than 4 results using Google APIs...? If yes, please share.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered reading the documentation from google? It can be found here:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

It talks about the API operations and models which should have some information on the parameters of the search function.

Comment: Yes ,what i am using is <b>Google Web Search API (Deprecated)</b> not the the Custom search API

Comment: Well if its deprecated you should maybe consider changing it anyway:

http://www.warriorforum.com/programming-talk/284155-google-web-search-api-deprecated.html

If you read that it tells you that they can terminate it at any point. You may wish to have a look at this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/google-web-search-api-deprecated-what-now