# What to use now Google News API is deprecated?

Tags: google-search-api

As part of a Project I'm working on I've been instructed to implement Google News API into a Web Application.

However, I've checked the [Google News API](http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/) site, and I see the following message:

> Important: The Google News Search API has been officially deprecated
>   as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation
>   policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be
>   limited.

I've checked [SO Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/google-web-search-api-deprecated-what-now) but I've not been able to find a question related to the News API.

- What should I use now that Google News API is redundant?
- Is it the Custom Search API?
- And if so, how can I make this relevant for just
  News Results for a particular query for my Web Application?

I've checked the [Google News RSS](http://news.google.com/news?q=apple&output=rss), but this uses HTML in the `description` which won't work for my requirements as I just need the text.

Comment: You can used R's tm.plugin.webmining package to extract news and text from GoogleNews (and others). More info @ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.webmining/index.html

Comment: If you are looking for an API to crawl news from multi sources, you could consider Newsriver (https://newsriver.io).
It's a very recent API to retrieve structured online news articles.
Newsriver covers a large number of sources, and it's fully configurable.

Comment: Try Faroo: http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html

Comment: You can use a third party solution like this API: https://serpapi.com/news-results

Comment: You can check for contextualwebsearch: https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search?endpoint=5b8644c1e4b09cbc25b00140.

Comment: Answer to the similar question about Google News scraping with code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015947/1291371

Comment: You can try this service from Rapid API rapidapi.com/anju.313/api/google-trends, But this is a paid service. Thanks

Comment: Aylien provides a News API that gives you access to NLP-enriched news articles from 80,000+ news sources: https://aylien.com/product/news-api/demo

Comment: You can extract URLs from the RSS feed and then extract the rest of the content (title, description, image) from the news source URL.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you want to use their section feeds, their search feeds

http://news.google.com/news?q=apple&output=rss

or Bing News Search.

http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/

Comment: The Google News RSS uses HTML in the `description` to display an image positioned next to the text. This won't work for my requirements as its too restrictive with the design I need to meet. I need the description to just be text, no HTML.

Comment: as you pointed out, google news api is deprecated so eitheir you do the work of stripping down the HTML or you use the Bing API. THere are not many alternatives

Comment: Cheers @nambrot, sorry its just I have to stick to requirements from the client. I'm currently seeing whether a switch to Bing would be okay!

Comment: what i am saying is you could strip down the html if it is that important to use google news. its non-commercial use only though

Comment: Ah right, I wasn't aware of that cheers!

Comment: cool, Can you tell what are the parameters(e.g. location etc) which we can pass to the google news url? http://news.google.com/news?q=apple&output=rss

Comment: i'm also wondering if i can filter by time/date.

Comment: any way to get next page results?

Comment: web.archive.org URL for search parameters: http://web.archive.org/web/20150204025359/http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/12975232033/google-news-search-parameters-the-missing-manual (@BrownyLin)

Comment: For those who wish to fetch google trends , Please use this service from Rapid API https://rapidapi.com/anju.313/api/google-trends

Comment: Aylien provides a News API that gives you access to NLP-enriched news articles from 80,000+ news sources: https://aylien.com/product/news-api/demo

Answer (score 12):

I'm running into the same issue with one of my own apps.  So far I've found the only non-deprecated way to access Google News data is through their [RSS feeds](http://www.google.com/support/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59255).  They have a feed for each section and also a useful search function.  However, these are only for noncommercial use.

As for viable alternatives I'll be trying out these two services: [Feedzilla](http://www.feedzilla.com/), [Daylife](http://developer.daylife.com/)

Comment: daylife link is dead

Comment: Are the RSS feeds still working?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you *might* have until the end of 2013 before they officially close it down.
http://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api/browse_thread/thread/6aaa1b3529620610/d70f8eec3684e431?lnk=gst&q=news+api#d70f8eec3684e431

Also, it sounds like they are building a replacement... but it's going to cost you.

I'd say, go to a different service.  I think bing has a news API.

You might enjoy (or not) reading: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1864625