# Google custom search engine for Google News

Tags: google-search-api, google-news

I'm trying to use the Google custom search engine API to query Google News. The API is working great otherwise - but I want to get News results instead of web results.

I can't find a way to either restrict the CSE to use Google News, or to ensure that my API query hits Google News rather than the web search. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use schemas from Schema.org to specify if you're only looking for articles/ blog posts.

To specify the Schema, go to Advanced settings on the [Control Panel](https://cse.google.com/cse/create/new) and select the required schema from [here](http://schema.org/docs/full.html).

Comment: Thanks! That's really useful to know.

Comment: Np! Sorry the Control Panel link is probably just taking you to the sign-in page.

Comment: I've actually worked on this and Google CSE is pretty far from ideal for making a news search engine. Schema.org types flag lots of nested content.

Comment: To people who are looking for the location to specify "Schema": it is NOT in the Advanced settings as of this writing.  It is in Setup(Left menu) > Basic > Restrict Pages using Schema.org Types.  Then according to Schema.org, the value entered should be "NewsArticle"

Answer (score 6):

There was a News Search API but it's **deprecated**:

> Important: The Google News Search API has been officially deprecated
>   as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation
>   policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be
>   limited.

https://developers.google.com/news-search/

You can see some alternatives SO users recommended on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806200/what-to-use-now-google-news-api-is-deprecated).

Comment: You're welcome :) don't forget to upvote / accept if I helped. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Update: I'm using [feedparser](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/introduction.html) and building RSS queries on the fly. Seems to work, though time will tell whether my IP gets banned for interface abuse :)