# google news Feed in the form of JSON

Tags: android, json, rss, feed

```
"The Google News Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited."
```

So i tried https://news.google.co.in/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=in&output=rss.

I got RSS Feed. but the description is containing proper HTML. But which is not suitable for android. So i need description as a string.
So how can i get it?

Comment: Answer to the similar question about Google News extraction in JSON format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015947/1291371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using https://newsapi.org/google-news-api.

This will give you Google News RSS Feed in JSON formate.

Comment: its free for only 500requests/day