# Get **last month or last year** google news using api

Tags: api, rss, google-search, google-custom-search, google-news

I have been trying get google news for the past month and the past year.
I have tried the following url but I cannot figure out what is the date parameter and what should be passed to it.

1. http://news.google.com/news/section?cf=all&ned=us&q=healthcare&num=10&output=rss
2. http://news.google.com/news/feeds?hl=en&q=healthcare&ie=utf-8&num=10&output=rss

Comment: Post on SU. This isn't valid on SO.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20150204025359/http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/12975232033/google-news-search-parameters-the-missing-manual):

> - as_qdr=m past month
> - as_qdr=y past year

Notice that due to Google News API is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7806200/4092887), maybe some parameters are no longer functional.

Check also this [answer on Stack Overflow and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829688/4092887) for get even more info about Google News API.