# What is the limit query of Google News API

Tags: google-news

Google news API has stop maintaine for a while; however, it is still function. We just continue use it. So the question is what is the limit of query using Google News?! 1,000/day, 2,000/day, Or other number?

Comment: You can use a third party solution like this one: https://serpapi.com/news-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty limited.

Related thread: [What to use now Google News API is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806200/what-to-use-now-google-news-api-is-deprecated).

Time to think about another news source.

Comment: But for us is actually enough, they have 64 entries limit per query... but it seems there is no query limit, which is great. The news media is not our core service, but it is great to have one, that's why we choose Google News. I have already read the article you provide, those API either too expensive to use or they don't have well international support. So Google News still the best match for our project.