# Google news rss parameter num 100 returning only 30 results

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss, feed, google-news

The link which i used to fetch results form google news

https://news.google.co.in/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=in&q=euro2016&csed=in&csep=false&num=100&sort=rated&output=rss

it is working fine but there is problem in number of results that i get.
the "num" parameter is returning maximum 30 results irrespective of the number when the num parameter exceeds 30

Has google changed the number of results that it gives. If yes is there any documentation of it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20150204025359/http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/12975232033/google-news-search-parameters-the-missing-manual):

> num=NUM retrieves NUM results. Default: 10. Possible values: if q present [1,100], otherwise [1, 30]

However, I tried *with no success* retreives the max limit results.

I think that due to Google News API is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7806200/4092887), some parameters are no longer functional.

Check also this [answer on Stack Overflow and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829688/4092887) for get even more info about Google News API.

Comment: i am also using the same parameter..it just stopped returning max results