# google news XML RSS by pagination or by date

Tags: google-news

i'm using google news to get news RSS by postal code

now i need to add pagination

or to get it from 1 day ago, 2 days ago ...

so far im using that url

```
https://news.google.com/news?geo=99553&output=rss
```

what i need for example is

```
https://news.google.com/news?geo=99553&output=rss&page=5
```

to get the 6th page of the news

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Comment: i just need the parameters to specify the date or page for example `geo` os the location that the news come from and it can be country, state or postal code

Comment: @robert, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39107737/4092887). it's possible that some parameters are no longer usable.