# How to integrate google play news in android app?

Tags: android, gridview, google-api

I want to integrate google news in my app same as "play Newsstand" app explore menu. Is it possible to get all the new which is showing in "play Newsstand" app ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can not integrate  Google Play Newsstand in our app
(Google still  not implemented that features)  .But we can can read articles from top news sources and magazines (in available markets) on Google Play Newsstand.

Comment: Thanks sasikumar. can you please suggest best api or any source where i get all the news.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806200/what-to-use-now-google-news-api-is-deprecated