# Alternatives to Google's Deprecated Image Search API?

Tags: google-custom-search, yahoo-boss-api, google-image-search

Since [Google Image Search API has been deprecated](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/) does Google provide any alternative to the Yahoo Search Boss API?

Is it possible to use the Google Custom Search API in a similar way to retrieve thumbnail images?

Comment: here is the answer if somebody else wonders too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated?rq=1