# google search API (CSE) returning very few results

Tags: api, search

So I followed the tips at 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206266/1456530 
(to remove the sites from custom search)

Currently I have no site here and I have selected "*search the entire web, but highlight things from this these sites*".

And I'm getting very few results, sometimes it is 1 result, or none at all. 
The result count `totalResults` is ridiculously low, like 1370 results for "*big flower*".
I am at a loss, and would be happy for any pointers to docs or whatever.

Does anybody have a good doc source?