# How to Get Google Web Search Results Using Python

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, web-search

I'd like to search Google programmatically using Python. I have about 1,000 queries I'd like to run, and all I need is the URL of the first result. Looking into this, I found the [Google Web Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/), which seems to fit the bil, but is now deprecated and only supports a limited number of queries per day. The replacement, the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) only seems to support searching specific websites, but I'd like to search the whole Internet (i.e., a normal Google search).

Is there any way to do 1,000 Google web searches using Python? I'm happy to pay a small fee in order to do that many queries, but it just seems like there's no longer an API that supports Google web searching.

Thanks.

Comment: Custom search can be configured for the whole Internet, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206266/2358842

Comment: Thank you, stackoverflow.com/a/11206266/2358842 is just what I was looking for!