# is there an API to get google search results (a non-deprecated api)?

Tags: php, rest, google-api

I would like to be able to use PHP to call a RESTful web service to get Google's search results. I saw (https://developers.google.com/web-search/) but it is deprecated.  I am not looking to make a custom search for my own site's content, but rather would like to use an API to get search results for the Internet.

Google's web site suggests "Custom Search API" (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), but I'm not sure if that is what I need.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Google earns milions of dolars on ads on search result pages so I think Google does not allow any API to take away that money. But maybe i'm wrong - see [Google web search API deprecated - what now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/google-web-search-api-deprecated-what-now?rq=1)

Comment: try these guys http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html

Comment: You have also this GitHub: https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-php

Answer (score 2):

Google's custom search API can be configured so that you can query the web rather than just your page, but you'll still cannot make more than 100 free calls per day, so it is essentially for testing. Similarly for the Yahoo API where you get some free calls after you register for billing. The only free API with a reasonable amount of free calls I know of is Faroo: http://www.faroo.com/hp/api/api.html
You can register for free there to get a key, then you can consume 1,000,000 free calls per month, which is probably enough for most applications. You can retrieve responses in JSON or XML, so implementing a PHP client should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Google is no longer offering the Search API.  I would recommend the Yahoo BOSS api.