# Google News Api custom search

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-news

I have this java script in my html file....I have a keyword search in my webpage, and I want to pass the keyword search to the API. This is what I currently have:  Not sure where I am going wrong that it is not producing any search results.

where I have

```
CNN
```

in the code, this is where my search variable should be passed...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('search', '1');

    function OnLoad()
    {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('CNN');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_
                                                             CSE_RESULTSET);
        customSearchControl.draw('cse');
        customSearchControl.execute("$q");
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

     // tell the searcher to draw itself and tell it where to attach
      // create a drawOptions object
      var drawOptions = new google.search.DrawOptions();

      // tell the searcher to draw itself in tabbed mode
      drawOptions.setDrawMode(google.search.SearchControl.DRAW_MODE_TABBED);
      searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("content"),drawOptions);

      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.NewsSearch());
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third party solution like this one: https://serpapi.com/news-results

It works in a very similar way as the Google regular search, just pass the `tbm=nws` to your url.

```
https://serpapi.com/search.json?q=Trump&tbm=nws&location=Dallas&hl=en&gl=us
```

Results:

```
{
  ...
  "news_results": [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "title": "Trump blasts Sessions over indictments of two of his earliest ...",
      "link": "https://www.cnn.com/2018/09/03/politics/donald-trump-jeff-sessions-justice-department/index.html",
      "source": "CNN",
      "date": "4 hours ago",
      "snippet": "(CNN) President Donald Trump on Monday blasted his Attorney General Jeff Sessions and lamented the indictments of two lawmakers who ...",
      "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCv3eR2GkOR3WgDNTd4LqT77Bteu_ScA8NUFKcEYU1HskYXHXrnse-GnG0SN78_uUgM1k0nIQV"
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "title": "Trump accuses Sessions of hurting Republican congressional races",
      "link": "https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trump-sessions/trump-accuses-sessions-of-hurting-republican-congressional-races-idUSKCN1LJ231",
      "source": "Reuters",
      "date": "3 hours ago"
    },
    {
      "position": 3,
      "title": "Trump steams at Attorney General Jeff Sessions, reigniting his attacks",
      "link": "https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/trump-steams-attorney-general-jeff-sessions-reigniting-attacks/story?id=57579418",
      "source": "ABC News",
      "date": "3 hours ago"
    },
    {
      "position": 4,
      "title": "Trump slams Sessions on Twitter, says AG is hurting GOP in midterms",
      "link": "http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2018/09/03/trump-slams-sessions-on-twitter-says-ag-is-hurting-gop-in-midterms.html",
      "source": "Fox News",
      "date": "4 hours ago"
    },
    {
      "position": 5,
      "title": "Trump blasts Sessions over charges against GOP congressmen ...",
      "link": "https://www.politico.com/story/2018/09/03/donald-trump-jeff-sessions-tweet-806298",
      "source": "Politico",
      "date": "5 hours ago"
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I think that the problem is these specialized CSEs have been 'deprecated' since 2010 ( see http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/) and now they just don't work. The new ones that do work are for general web search and image search. You can probably restrict the web search one to the CNN site if that's your goal. See [What are the alternatives now that the Google web search API has been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/google-web-search-api-deprecated-what-now)