# Google custom search - limit exceeded error on first request?

Tags: google-custom-search

I've just signed up for the google custom search api, and have defined my engine using the control panel, and edited it as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206266.  I then headed over to http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list in order to test the JSON API as described in the (fairly poor) documentation.  I pasted a simple query in the 'q' field and my search engine ID from the control panel in the 'cx' field, and then in the 'fields' section I selected all of the possible response types, but I'm getting the following result for any query I attempt:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

Why has my daily limit been exceeded when I only signed up for the service 10 minutes ago and have not yet issued any requests?

Comment: The Explorer documentation says that it uses it's own quota (and key) to make requests, not yours: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/ This means that most probably it was a glitch or a bug in Explorer and not your engine (it seems to be working fine for me now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Explorer documentation says that it uses it's own quota (and key) to make requests, not yours: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/

This means that most probably it was a glitch or a bug in Explorer and not your engine (it seems to be working fine for me now). Try to issue request from your application with your API key and the problem should be resolved.

If you just want to try to issue a single request without writing code you can use Postman Chrome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en