# How to fetch the logo of any website in android?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on a Project in which the input is URL and the output is the website Logo. There are some websites like Facebook,Youtube, yahoo etc which uses CSS to make their logo attractive, So how can i fetch the logo of these websites.
I have written the following code to fetch the logo of those websites which uses Logo image :

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
        for (Element element : elements) {

            //Searching the src tag inside img tag
            logo =element.attr("src");
            String logo1=logo;

            //If src link has substring logo 
            if(logo1.toLowerCase().contains("logo")|| element.attr("alt").toLowerCase().contains("logo"))
            {
                if(!logo.contains("http"))
                {
                    if(!logo.startsWith("/"))
                        logo=link + "/"+logo;
                    else
                        logo=link+logo;
                }
                System.out.println(logo);
                logoflag=1;

            }

        }
```

Comment: you might need to research with at least 1,000 website to get their name of their's logo. some website use their website name as logo's name, some website use their company name as logo's name, etc.

Comment: lot of website put there logo on browser tab.they use `shortcut icon` for that.
for example this is the code for facebook
`<link href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/yl/r/H3nktOa7ZMg.ico" rel="shortcut icon">`  and stackoverflow `<link href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=6cd6089ee7f6" rel="shortcut icon">` you can get icon url easily

Comment: Thank you @FastSnail for usefull support. It will help me alot.

Comment: @FastSnail can i use the google image api and then fetch the logo from there in Android?

Comment: @jackson that will work for popular sites .but i think google image api is depreciated ?

Comment: Ok. but the shortcut icon for most of the websites are very small.

Comment: yes that is a problem.

Comment: So is there any Other Alternate method?

Comment: i think google image search api is the best option .so read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated