# Ruby script to print the number of total results on google

Tags: ruby, google-search, google-search-api, google-query-language

I want to make ruby script to print the number of total results on google **when searched using a queries** like `allinurl: http://www.example.net/Downloads.aspx?Doc=`

I went through the source code of the page and made the following ruby script

```
require "rubygems"
require "rest-client"

url="https://www.google.com.np/search?q=allinurl:+http://www.dpsmathuraroad.net/Downloads.aspx%3FDoc%3D&lr=&safe=active&hl=en&noj=1&biw=1366&bih=643&filter=0"
intel=RestClient.get(url)

xfile=File.open("dpsmathuraroad.txt","w")
xfile.write(intel.body)
xfile.close

xfile2=File.open("dpsmathuraroad.txt", "r")
while !xfile2.eof?
    ch=xfile2.readline
    if ch=~ /<div id="resultStats">About /
        break
    end
end
dat=ch.split(/[<div id="sbfrm_l"><div id="resultStats">About , results<nobr> ]/)
puts dat[1]
gets
```

the line `dat=ch.split(/[<div id="sbfrm_l"><div id="resultStats">About , results<nobr> ]/)` in the code above is pure manipulation from the source code of the page.

BUT UNFORTUNATELY GOOGLE DOES HUMAN CHALLENGE AND A **CAPTCHA** THUS INTERFERES.

How do I get past the interfering captcha and get the desired result with such ruby scripts? Can it be done using some APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's exactly why Captchas exist. Scraping of any kind violates Google's terms of service, and they use Captchas to enforce that.

Sorry.

Comment: I've heard that it can be done using google search api. If not then please tell me.

Comment: @Rishav see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind breaking their terms of service, there are APIs for Captcha solving. These are often used in results scrapers, such as [Serposcope](https://serposcope.serphacker.com/en/).

For example [anti-captcha](https://anti-captcha.com/).