# how to use doGoogleSearch() method , I am failing to get a key from http://www.google.com/apis/

Tags: asp.net, google-search, google-search-api

my purpose is to get 'google search result' and collect all the links returned by google search. Learned on web that doGoogleSearch() method can be used to get results, failing to get a required key from http://www.google.com/apis/

how should I progress ? I am using (ASP.NET)

(I am following this link http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/search-google-aspnet)

Answer (score 1):

That guide is very old (2009). Google Web Search API was deprecated in 2010, and closed down entirely in 2014. Some possible alternatives are suggested here: [What are the alternatives now that the Google web search API has been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated)