# Catch only websites links in Google search Results

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I have the following code:

```
$urls = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/#q=test');

preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z]*.com/i', $urls, $content);

$i = 10;

while ( $i <= 50 ) {
$i+= 10;

$urls2 = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/#q=test&start=".$i."'); // pagination Google search Results

preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z]*.com/i', $urls2, $contentLoop);

$totalArray = array_push($content,$contentLoop);


}

print_r($totalArray);
```

This only print number 6

In the while, how do I add several arrays within a single array?

I tried to use the function array_push, but got no success so far

Comment: array_push returns int. Try to print $content instead

Comment: Try using PHP simple html dom class to get content from web. It`s much easier to get wanted data. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 0):

Array_push is used to push only one element to the end of array. You can use here one of two possible solutions (both would save your data into $content array):

1. Use array_merge.

   ```
   array_merge($content,$contentLoop);
   ```
2. Loop through $contentLoop.

   ```
   foreach($contentLoop as $item){
       array_push($content,$item);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine two `arrays` in a single one then you can use
`array_merge` — Merge one or more arrays.

e.g.

```
<?php
$totalArray = array_merge($content,$contentLoop);
print_r($totalArray);
?>
```

Check official documentation here:

[array_merge — Merge one or more arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to scrape Google search results. Scraping is against the Google terms of service. Google had a web search api but it was discontinued in 2014. Google now provides a custom search api. [What are the alternatives now that the Google web search API has been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated)