# Getting the Error 403 Forbidden while posting the website address through Perl

Tags: perl

```
use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $UserAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $UserAgent->get("https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar_lookup?author=N.+R.+Alpert&author=S.+A.+Mohiddin&author=D.+Tripodi&author=J.+Jacobson-Hatzell&author=K.+Vaughn-Whitley&author=C.+Brosseau+&publication_year=2005&title=Molecular+and+phenotypic+effects+of+heterozygous,+homozygous,+and+compound+heterozygote+myosin+heavy-chain+mutations&journal=Am.+J.+Physiol.+Heart+Circ.+Physiol.&volume=288&pages=H1097-H1102");

if ($response->is_success)

{

$response->content =~ /<title>(.*?) - Google Scholar<\/title>/;

print $1;
}

else

{

die $response->status_line;

}
```

I am getting the below error while running this script.

**403 Forbidden at D:\Getelement.pl line 52.**

I have pasted this website address in address bar, and its redirecting exactly to that site, but its not working in while running by script.

Can you please help me on this issue.

Comment: What's in line 52?

Comment: @simbabque probably `die $response->status_line;`

Answer (score 2):

Google  Terms  of Service  [disallow  automated  searches](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en). They  are
detecting you're  sending this  from a script  because your  headers and
your browser  standard headers are  very different, and you  can analyze
them if you want.

In the  old times they had  a SOAP API,  and you could use  modules like
[`WWW::Search::Google`](http://search.cpan.org/~lbrocard/WWW-Search-Google-0.23/Google.pm) but that's not  the case anymore because this
API was deprecated.

Alternatives  were  already  discussed in  the  following  StackOverflow
question:

- [What  are the alternatives  now that the  Google web search  API has
  been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Google has blacklisted `LWP::UserAgent` They either blacklisted the UserAgent or parts of the request (headers whatsoever).

I suggest you use [Mojo::UserAgent.](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent). The request looks like by default more like a browser. You must write minimum 1 lines of code.

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use strict;
use warnings;

print Mojo::UserAgent->new->get('https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar_lookup?author=N.+R.+Alpert&author=S.+A.+Mohiddin&author=D.+Tripodi&author=J.+Jacobson-Hatzell&author=K.+Vaughn-Whitley&author=C.+Brosseau+&publication_year=2005&title=Molecular+and+phenotypic+effects+of+heterozygous,+homozygous,+and+compound+heterozygote+myosin+heavy-chain+mutations&journal=Am.+J.+Physiol.+Heart+Circ.+Physiol.&volume=288&pages=H1097-H1102')->res->dom->at('title')->text;

# Prints Molecular and phenotypic effects of heterozygous, homozygous, and      
# compound heterozygote myosin heavy-chain mutations - Google Scholar
```

**Terms**

The code does not accept any terms nor additional lines has been added to bypass security checks. It's absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to get the data which is present in the tag <h3 class="gs_rt"> instead of <title>. I have used the code "my $response = $UserAgent->get($xtx1)->res->dom->at('<h3 class="gs_rt">')->text;" but its getting error. Could you please suggest.

Comment: @Siva try $UserAgent->get($xtx1)->res->dom->at('h3.gs_rt')->text;    PS: Don't forget to accept my answer, if my example suits your needs. :-)

Comment: Hi, its not working out, its printing the blank line

Comment: Then you gave me the wrong DOM. The HTML must look like this <h3 class="gs_rt">Text123</h3>, if there are more selectors such as span a href before the text, they need to be specified.

Comment: @Siva ->res->dom->at('h3.gs_rt a')->text;  It prints Molecular and phenotypic effects of heterozygous, homozygous, and compound heter
ozygote myosin heavy-chain mutations

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch your content if you add a User Agent string to identify yourself to the web server:

```
...
my $UserAgent = LWP::UserAgent-new;
$UserAgent->agent('Mozilla/5.0'); #...add this...
...
print $1;
...
```

This prints: "Molecular and phenotypic effects of heterozygous, homozygous, and compound heterozygote myosin heavy-chain mutations"