# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Google results when I search "*What is 2+2*", but the following code is returning `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. Please help me in achieving the required goal.

```
text="What is 2+2"
search=text.replace(" ","+")
link="https://www.google.com/search?q="+search
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
source=requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")
answer=soup.find('span',id="cwos")

self.respond(answer.text)
```

The only problem is with `id` in `soup.find`, however I have chosen this id very closely. I shouldn't be mistaken. I also tried `answer=soup.find('span',class_="cwcot gsrt")`, but neither worked.

Comment: The `<span>` with the id `cwos` was not found and the result of the `find()` became `None`. You should handle this case.

Comment: I can't see that id by entering your link in browser. What is the expected text to be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time use the query string exactly as it is.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
search="2%2B2"
link="https://www.google.com/search?q="+search
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}
source=requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")
answer=soup.find('span',id="cwos")
print(answer.text)
```

Output:

```
 4
```

Visit these urls - they do not return the same result

https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+2+2

https://www.google.com/search?q=2%2B2

https://www.google.com/search?q=2+2

Answer (score 5):

A big gotcha when parsing websites is that the source code can look very different in your browser when compared to what `requests` sees. The difference is javascript, which can hugely modify the DOM in a javascript capable browser.

I'd suggest 3 options:

1. use `requests` to get the page, and then examine it closely - does that tag exist when the page is retrieved by a non-js enabled agent?
2. use https://www.seleniumhq.org/ as your agent - it's essentially a fully featured browser that you can control programatically, inc w/ python.
3. use google's search API instead of trying to scrape the html

Comment: `Use Google's search API`: What API are you referring to? AFAIK, Google hasn’t had a public search API for [well over 8 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated).

Comment: Boy do I feel old, I had no idea o.O

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code, you might encounter an AttributeError:

**shell: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

If that’s the case, then take a step back and inspect your previous results. Were there any items with a value of None? You might have noticed that the structure of the page is not entirely uniform. There could be an advertisement in there that displays in a different way than the normal job postings, which may return different results

Reference:https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/#extract-text-from-html-elements.