# Getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to the python and dyjango. I am trying to make a **scraper** using BeautifulSoup. My site has a search form where user searches for products that am using BeautifulSoup to **scrape** amazon.in to show the results to the user.

Everything works fine but it gives me two types of error sometime it gives me the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_search.search

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

and sometimes it gives the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Ahmed\codelist\myapp\views.py", line 24, in new_search
    post_title = post.find(class_='a-section').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
[15/Mar/2020 13:34:15] "POST /new_search HTTP/1.1" 500 87165
```

my **views.py**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render
from requests.compat import quote_plus
from . import models

BASE_AMAZON_URL = 'https://www.amazon.in/s?k={}'

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def new_search(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    models.Search.objects.create(search=search)
    final_url = BASE_AMAZON_URL.format(quote_plus(search))
    response = requests.get(final_url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')

    post_listings = soup.find_all('', {'class': 's-result-list'})

    final_postings = []
    for post in post_listings:
        post_title = post.find(class_='a-section').text
        post_url = post.find('a').get('href')
        post_price = post.find(class_='a-price').text

        final_postings.append((post_title, post_url, post_price))

    stuff_for_frontend = {
    'search': search,
    'final_postings': final_postings,
    }
    return render(request, 'myapp/new_search.html', stuff_for_frontend)
```

my **new_search.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">{{ search | title }}</h2>

    {% for post in final_postings %}
    <p>{{ post.0 }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.1 }}</p>
    <p>{{ post.2 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53980144/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: fyi it's __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrapper

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous):

> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This usually happens because you called `find()` and then tried to access the .foo attribute of the result. But in your case, `find()` didn’t find anything, so it returned `None`, instead of returning a tag or a string. You need to figure out why your `find()` call isn’t returning anything.

It could not find an element you searched for at this line, and returned `None`: `post_title = post.find(class_='a-section').text`