# Creation of a Google Search with a TextBox

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a google search with a text box. So how would I do that? I already have my web browser and stuff set up, but I am needing to now do the google search term. And to search, I want a key press down event that would then (if they press the enter key) it would search up the text in the box. How would I do this?

Comment: please explain properly what you want?

Comment: Note that the `[visual-studio]` tag should only be used for questions about Visual Studio.

Comment: @karan I want to make a google search text box so users in my browser can type in like "youtube" and once you click "enter" it will search the term "youtube" on my tab control.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated has some options. Bear in mind google isn't the only search engine, there might be better (cheaper or easier) alternatives.

Comment: What kind of application are you making, OP? Web? Desktop? What technologies are you working with (e.g. WinForms, WPF, WebForms, etc.)? What attempt have you made to solve this problem yourself?

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]

Since you never mentioned you were developing on WPF I have edited my answer.

Make a handler that will trigger the search, and add this inside the code block:

```
string strUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox.Text);
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(strUrl);
proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Should I put this in my "KeyDown" "enter" button? Since I want when you click "enter" it searches up whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, make a handler that will trigger the search and then add it inside the code block

Comment: @Jovan will this work if OP is making a WinForms or WPF application?

Comment: @Jovan It is giving me these two errors.
The name 'Response' does not exist in this current context.
The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in this current context.

Comment: @John nope you will need this:

string strUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox.Text);

Process proc = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(strUrl);

proc.StartInfo = startInfo;

proc.Start();

Comment: @gr8devin23 You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54453955/edit) with your current code. Note that Jovan's code is for web applications, not desktop applications.

Comment: @John oh... How would I do this in a desktop application?

Comment: @Jovan
It is still giving me this one error; 'The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in this current context'

Comment: You can use  Uri.EscapeUriString() instead of HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Comment: Ok, it isn't giving me more errors. But it won't search anything, is there anyway I can contact you to make this easier? (such as discord) Then I could explain how you would do it on stack overflow.

Comment: @Jovan mention .