# how to scrape google result progressively?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-search, time-to-first-byte

I want to scrape google as fast as possible. Google in browser loads progressively in which loading results is divided into `Waiting(TTFB)` and `Content Downlaod`.

[image]

I am using `python requests` to scrape google. The timing of `requests` is only `Waiting(TTFB)` and a little `Content Download`.

[image]

Code is as below:

```
google_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&start={}'.\
        format(escaped_search_term, size, offset)
response = self.session.get(google_url, verify=False,
                            headers={'User-Agent': self.USER_AGENT})
return response.text
```

I want to load result as fast as possible, so i have to download google results progressively like browser. How can i do this?

Comment: I think you would need to use Google Custom Search API, per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated .  It will potentially cost money.  If you don't use it, it could violate Google's TOS.

Comment: @alex thanks for reply. My problem is getting results is so slow. I think even if i use Google Custom Search API the problem remains.

Comment: Do you mean that their API is slow or your code execution is slow?

Comment: @alex I guess my code execution is slow. I want to download web page progressively like `stream` in downloading file, But i do not know how.

Comment: If the goal is to only download HTML in a streaming fashion, adapt code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39217788/1291371).

1. The total time to download is only 30 ms less for the request from the browser.
2. Is Python has a streaming HTML parser? If you're going to write response stream to file (in-memory or disk), read contents of the file, and parse it with `bs4`, then I don't see performance benefits of doing this.

Comment: @IlyaZub thanks for response. when I set `stream` as True response takes more time to download and total page is receiving in first callback so it does not help. any way I realized that google does not send search results progressively. google sends header of page at the first then sleeps for a while then sends all results together in at most 3 packets. so downloading page progressively does not help.